# go - checking if key of one map present in another

Tags: go

I have one dictionary

```
a = {1:11, 2:22}
```

I want to check if key in `b` is present in `a` or not

```
b = {3:33, 1:11}
```

How can I do this in Go language?

I have done it like this:

```
a:= make(map[string][]string)
a["1"] = append(a["1"], "11")
a["1"] = append(a["1"], "22")
```

I have a dict `b` as:

```
b:= make(map[string]string)
b["1"] = "11"
```

How can I check this? Essentially, I want to check if key `1` from `b` is present in `a` or not.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use the go idiomatic way to check for a key presence:

```
if _, ok:= b[key]; ok
```

**Example:**

```
var (
    a = map[string]int{
        "alpha": 34, "bravo": 56, "charlie": 23,
        "delta": 87, "echo": 56, "foxtrot": 12, "golf": 34, "hotel": 16,
        "indio": 87, "juliet": 65, "kilo": 43, "lima": 98}

    b = map[string]int{
        "alpha": 34, "one": 56, "charlie": 23,
        "insdio": 87, "julietta": 65, "kilo": 43, "lima": 98}
)

func main() {
    for key, _ := range a {
        if _, ok:= b[key]; ok {         
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", key)
        }
    }   
}
```

[Playground Example 1](https://play.golang.org/p/qCq5_zn7Fd)

Or you can check if the key value from the first map corresponds to the value from the second map:

```
for key, val := range a {
    if val == b[key] {          
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", key)
    }
}
```

[Playground Example 2](https://play.golang.org/p/tf95-qcRAW)

But the first one is the idiomatic way.